# safeAreaInsets is 0 only on iPhone 7 Plus / 8 Plus

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I am positioning a view relative to the bottom of the screen, and since this view launches in my app delegate, I am setting it's coordinates relative to the bottom safeAreaInset. However, on both the iPhone 7 Plus and 8 Plus, the positioning is off, and when I check the safeAreaInsets, it reports that it is 0.  Why would this happen just on iPhone 7 Plus and 8 Plus, and is there a workaround?  Would it be best to add conditional code only for those devices?

EDIT:
I found out that in landscape mode I needed to use safeAreaInserts.left rather than safeAreaInserts.bottom - that solved my issue.

Comment: can you please add your storyboard/xib details and code if any changes are done with code?

Answer (score 0):

If you view is completely within the safe area then the safeAreaInsets will be 0.

Do you have a tab bar? If not then the safe area inset on the bottom is expected to be 0 (except for iPhone X and up).

What other devices have you observed and what values did they have?

In most cases writing conditional code would not be required.

Comment: I found out that in landscape mode I needed to use safeAreaInserts.left rather than safeAreaInserts.bottom - that solved my issue.